# Class not found for a parent class

Tags: php, class

Hi guys i cant find the error on this one i'm new in oop. I'm trying to access the parentClass, but it keeps on saying NewClass not found tho i declared it

```
// here is the code

//oop1_index.php
       <?php
       include "oop1.php";
        include "oop1_parentclass.php";

          $object = new NewClass;
?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
       <title>OOP</title>
     </head>
<body>

<?php
    echo $object->name;


?>  

</body>
</html>
```

//oop1.php this is the document for my NewClass

```
<?php

class NewClass extends  parentClass {

}



?>
```

//oop1_parentclass.php this is where my parentClass is located

```
<?php

class parentClass{
    public $info = "This is info";

}

?>
```

Comment: Switch the include's functions so first you'll include the oop1_parentclass.php file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `NewClass` in `oop1.php` file don't know what is `parentClass`. When you calling `include "oop1.php"`, PHP will immediately call the code inside `oop1.php` file, so PHP will try to declare `NewClass`. On this step you still didn't declare `parentClass` and that's why you see this error.

My suggestion about fixing that problem:

1. Don't use `include`, use `require_once` instead. You can read the difference in phpdocs. (The most brilliant variant is to learn about  [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and use [composer autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) instead of manual requiring every file).
2. Move requiring `oop1_parentclass.php` inside the `oop1.php` file.
3. You can find working example [here](https://gist.github.com/kaduev13/6513f3fa4dc0d50de45296221c761205).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @erwin happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If classes are in different files you have to include one file into the "main" one. There also exist composer, a packet manager that helps you in doing that by using the namespaces of the files (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md, see autoloading).

 Without using composer, try that:

```
<?php

require_once 'oop1_parentclass.php';
class NewClass extends  parentClass {

}

?>
```

Then the second file:

```
class parentClass{
    public $info = "This is info";

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

include "oop1.php";
/*
//oop1.php this is the document for my NewClass
class NewClass extends  parentClass {}
*/

include "oop1_parentclass.php";
/*
//oop1_parentclass.php this is where my parentClass is located
class parentClass{ ...
*/


 $object = new NewClass;
?>
```

So you're calling extends on a class which doesn't exist.
**Switch** your include functions so you'd firstly include the parentClass declaration and only afterwards the defination of the NewClass.

**Updated code should be:**

```
include "oop1_parentclass.php";
include "oop1.php";
$object = new NewClass;
```